# Python Pandas Dataframe Pulling cell value of Column B based on Column A

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

struggling here. Probably missing something incredibly easy, but beating my head on my desk while trying to learn Python and realizing that's probably not going to solve this for me.

I have a dataframe `df` and need to pull the value of column B based on the value of column A.

Here's what I can tell you of my dataset that should make it easier. Column A is unique (FiscalYear) but despite being a year was converted `to_numeric`. Column B is not specifically unique (Sales) and like Column A was converted to `to_numeric`. This is what I have been trying as I was able to do this when finding the value of sales using idx max. However at a specific value, this is returning an error:

```
v = df.at[df.FiscalYear == 2007.0, 'Sales']
```

I am getting `ValueError: At based indexing on an integer index can only have integer indexers` I am certain that I am doing something wrong, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

And here's the code that is working for me.

```
v = df.at[df.FiscalYear.idxmax(), 'Sales']
```

No issues there, returning the proper value, etc.

Any help is appreciated. I saw a bunch of similar threads, but for some reason searching and blindly writing lines of code is failing me tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use .loc method

```
df.Sales.loc[df.FiscalYear==2007.0]
```

this will be pandas series type object.
if you want it in a list you can do:

```
df.Sales.loc[df.FiscalYear==2007.0].tolist()
```

Comment: Is there any way to pull this as a string or a number? Lets say I wanted to pull the value of the cell, and then add that to another dataframe. Or would the series type object work with just a singular value?

Comment: if you want to extract a cell value, you can use the same method, using loc, but instead of `.tolist()` use `.item()`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
v = df.at[df.FiscalYear.eq(2007.0).index[0], 'Sales']
```